# Progression free survival calculation by months using PROC LIFETEST

Tags: sas

I have this section of a table which compares 2 drugs

[image]

and this piece of of code (AvalM is Aval transformed to months using this code avalM = aval / 365.25 * 12;)

```
    PROC LIFETEST data = adtte00 METHOD = km CONFTYPE=LOGLOG ;
    TIME avalM * CNSR(1) ;
    STRATA trtp;
    by &Subgrp;
    RUN;
```

Now I know there is an option in PROC LIFETEST for plots such as

```
plots=survival(atrisk= 0 to 2500 by 500)
```

Can something similar be done here just to get the results for each month specified and can the by statement be adjusted as the pattern is 3,6,9,12,18,24 so the first 4 are every 3 months but the rest are every 6 months. Any help would be greatly appreciated.